# how to format my C++ code like this?

Tags: coding-style, ide

To notify in advance, Astyle can't do this for me.
I want my code to align right. It would make me crazy if I have to type space manually. As you can see after modification, the code is much more beautiful.

**I want to know what's the best method to do it? anybody can help me?**

Here is the original code:

```
unsigned __int64 contentsStmSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 imageSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 fontSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 bookMarkSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 xObjectFormsSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 structureInfoSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 acroFormsSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 linkAnnotsSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 namedDestnationsSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 docOverheadSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 clrSpaceSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 patternInfoSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 shadingPatternInfoSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 extGraphicsStatesSize = 0;
unsigned __int64 crossRefTableSize              = 0;
```

and here is what I want:

```
unsigned __int64 contentsStmSize                = 0;
unsigned __int64 imageSize                      = 0;
unsigned __int64 fontSize                       = 0;
unsigned __int64 bookMarkSize                   = 0;
unsigned __int64 xObjectFormsSize               = 0;
unsigned __int64 structureInfoSize              = 0;
unsigned __int64 acroFormsSize                  = 0;
unsigned __int64 linkAnnotsSize                 = 0;
unsigned __int64 namedDestnationsSize           = 0;
unsigned __int64 docOverheadSize                = 0;
unsigned __int64 clrSpaceSize                   = 0;
unsigned __int64 patternInfoSize                = 0;
unsigned __int64 shadingPatternInfoSize         = 0;
unsigned __int64 extGraphicsStatesSize          = 0;
unsigned __int64 crossRefTableSize              = 0;
```

Comment: use the `TAB` key to align

Comment: This is mostly related to the ide or text editor you use, it has nothing to do with C++/C other than the fact that the code sample is written in it.

Comment: "More beautiful" is a *very* individual and biased opinion. There are as many coding styles and opinions about what beautiful code is as there are programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In emacs you can select the lines and then type

```
ctrl-alt-shift-5
\(.*?\) *= 0;
\,(format "%-50s = 0;" \1)
```

Meaning is

- `\(.*?\)` grab everything (non greedy to leave the spaces out)
- `*= 0;` a sequence of spaces followed by `=` a space and `0;`
- `\,` replace with the value of elisp expression
- `(format "%-50s = 0;" \1)` format group 1 as a left-aligned string of size 50 followed by the end part `" = 0;"`

Note that however this style of indentation is sort of annoying to keep updated (e.g. when you add a new variable with a name longer than the others) and this is the reason for which it's discouraged in many code style conventions.

Answer (score 2):

I like this style too. And I use to align my code with tabs to see the values better. 
One help that I use too is to select some code lines with ALT + Mouse and with the tab button you can realign a group of lines at the same time.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too hard in vi. Search for '=' (`/=`<kbd>enter</kbd>), Insert tab (`i`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>). Then hit `.` a few times to align one line, and `n` to go to the next spot.

```
1G/=
i^I^[.....n.....n...n...n... etc.
```